# How can one manually orient the a Camera object in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, camera, flash-cs5

I've been working on an iPhone app developed with Flash CS5 that will stream the camera view to a window on the app screen. The camera code is as follows:

```
cam.setMode(600, 400, 25); 
cam.setQuality(0, 100);
vid             = new Video();
vid.width       = cam.width;
vid.height      = cam.height;
vid.attachCamera(cam);

vid.x = Main.stage.stageWidth / 2 - vid.width / 2;
vid.y = 50;

addChild(vid);
```

I set the iPhone to stay in a portrait orientation constantly by setting `stage.autoOrients = false` and `stage.setOrientation( StageOrientation.DEFAULT )`. However, the camera still displays as if the phone was flipped 90 degrees to the left. How can I change it so the program stays in portrait orientation and the camera is oriented correctly?

Comment: Hey I don't have an answer for this and I also would like to know as I'm having the same issue trying to write up a AS3/AIR QR code reader using ZXing from what I see in the Camera (AS3 reference) class it just expects it to be landscape for some reason (I don't get the logic there), my guess is we could use a transform matrix to do the translate, rotate, translate on the vid to correct the orientation, though I don't see how there's no better way.  I'm "favoriting" this question, hopefully that alerts me when anything changes, but I'll check back.  Good luck.

Comment: hey just FYI I ended up going with the same route suggested below, offset the component to make up for the the registration point being in the top left corner, so I rotate 90 degrees then slide it back into place, this works well for now, also note in AIR 3.2 SDK apparently you should be able to use the StageVideo to attach a camera (and can do orthogonal rotations, and grab bitmap data) this all according to a pre-release post I read from Thiabult at Google but if that all is in fact available it's probably a better way to go to get GPU acceleration, just figured I'd put it out there.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties panel there's a drop down that specifies Air for iOS click the wrench beside it("edit aplication settings") -> Make sure the Aspect Ratio is oriented to portrait.

may also want to try:

```
vid.rotation = -90;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have confirmed that the aspect ratio was always Portrait. Rotating the video kind of works, but as a workaround, because the entire video object becomes rotated, not just the output. That includes the registration point and height/width values. That also means that if I port to another device that has a smarter camera, it will automatically rotate it, whether it's right or not.

Comment: That seems like it would be a problem, though as far as i know there is no way to directly grab camera orientation ... it's just a feed. you could try isolating device by using [flash.system.Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os)